# sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file in Airflow

Tags: sqlite, airflow, data-pipeline

So I am trying to use sqlite database for my airflow project.
I set up the database and connected it to my Airflow project (which I am running using Docker)

`airflow connections get podcasts`
[image]

The connection is pointed to the correct directory.

But when I run the pipeline, I get the following error

```
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql.py", line 274, in execute
    **extra_kwargs,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/hooks/sql.py", line 342, in run
    with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn:
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/sqlite/hooks/sqlite.py", line 41, in get_conn
    conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_uri, uri=True)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

How can I fix it?